# How can EncoderFallbackExceptions caused by invalid utf16 surrogates be ignored when Console.Out.Encoding is UTF8?

Tags: c#, unicode, utf-16, console-output

I've observed, using Visual studio 2008 (with .NET 3.5), that the the value of `Console.Out.Encoding` changes based upon if running via a debugger and Console App/Windows App in the following way:

- GUI App - using debugger

  - System.Text.SBCSCodePageEncoding
- GUI App - not using a debugger

  - System.Text.UTF8Encoding
- Console App - using a debugger

  - System.Text.SBCSCodePageEncoding
- Console App - not using a debugger

  - System.Text.SBCSCodePageEncoding

Now when `Console.Out.Encoding` is set to `SBCSCodePageEncoding` it doesn't throw exceptions when invalid utf16 surrogates written to it. For example:

```
string invalidStringContiaingHighOrderSurrogateWithOutMatchingLowOrderSurrogate = '\uD81B'.ToString() + ";";
Console.WriteLine(invalidStringContiaingHighOrderSurrogateWithOutMatchingLowOrderSurrogate);
Console.Out.Flush();
```

However when `Console.Out.Encoding` is set to `System.Text.UTF8Encoding` writing invalid utf16 surrogates to it throws `System.Text.EncoderFallbackException`.

I want to be a able to ignore EncoderFallbackExceptions without having to add a try catch block to each use of `Console.Out` in the large windows application I working with. How can I do this?

1. Changing to a console app is NOT an acceptable solution.
2. Somehow changing Console.Out.Encoding to SBCSCodePageEncoding IS a acceptable solution.
3. I can't change Console.Out.Encoding.EncoderFallback as I get the following exception `System.InvalidOperationException` "Instance is readonly"
4. The win32 function SetConsoleOutputCP seemed to have no effect on my GUI/Windows app.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`Console.OutputEncoding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.outputencoding.aspx) property to set the encoding however you want.

(Personally I'd stick with UTF-8, but create an `UTF8Encoding`, setting an appropriate [`EncoderFallback`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.encoderfallback.aspx) value, e.g. [`ReplacementFallback`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoderfallback.replacementfallback.aspx).)

Comment: Doesn't that only work for Console apps or am I doing somthing wrong? Console.OutputEncoding = new UTF8Encoding(); throws IOException "the handle is invalid" for Windows/GUI applications.

Comment: That's very odd. I guess it depends on what you're expecting to do with the console output in a GUI app to start with. Do you just want it in the output window in VS?

Comment: Yes when running in a debugger the output is intended for VS (Output/Debug window or intermediate window depending on developers settings) - I guess I could just add IsDebuggerAttached calls before the Console.WriteLines but that's only marginally better than wrapping them in try catch blocks.

Comment: Note that changes to encoding in `Console` were made in both .NET 4.0 and .NET 4.5 (also these versions are mentioned on the first page you link, in _Remarks_ section). The poster uses .NET 3.5, I think. Not sure if this is relevant though.

Comment: Yep - using .NET 3.5 I will update the question to make that clear. Thanks